# Application exits after file download

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've created an ASP.Net Core MVC web application to execute a stored procedure on my local SQL server, and return the results in a CSV file for the user to download.

Everything works fine, and I can even download the file, except the application just completely stops running and exits after I save the file. The only error in the console is:

> The program 'dotnet' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The issue didn't start happening until I added in the parameters to pull the values from the input boxes on the form. Before I added the parameters to pull into the query, the issue was not happening.

Is there something else I'm missing to get the application to continue to run even after the file is downloaded?

Here is my code that runs when the user clicks a button to download the CSV file:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ExportCSV([FromForm] string VoterType, [FromForm] string CountyName, [FromForm] string PartyName)
        {
            
            string constr = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build().GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["FLVDCS"];
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC get_voters '" + CountyName + "', '" + PartyName + "', '" + VoterType + "';"))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);

                            var builder = new StringBuilder();
                            string csv = string.Empty;

                            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                            {
                                csv += column.ColumnName + ',';
                            }

                            builder.AppendLine(csv);
                            csv = String.Empty;

                            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                                {
                                    csv += row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ",";
                                }

                                builder.AppendLine(csv);
                                csv = String.Empty;
                            }

                            return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString()), "text/csv", CountyName + "_" + PartyName + "_" + VoterType + "_" + "Voters" + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".csv");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: You're not running this in debug mode and closing the browser that was started up when you ran the code, are you?

Comment: Please never use a String to concatenate more than once or twice. Use a `StringBuilder` as it wont create a new object on the managed heap each concatenation. **With the info you've provided we can't help much further**

Comment: @JeremyThompson That and OP should probably use `SqlDataReader` and not read it all into a `DataTable` just to loop through its rows and generate a CSV file.

Comment: I wasn't closing the browser window, but it looks like debug mode might be the issue here. When I run it without debugging, it works fine. I ignorantly didn't even think about this. Thank you!!!

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar If I knew how to do that I would! This is code I was able to put together just from searching online on how to do what I want.

Comment: Since it doesn't relate to your question, I won't add this an an answer, but I'd suggest changing your code to be like this: https://pastebin.com/hChcD1KC (although using a dedicated CSV library such as CsvHelper might be better since you could have commas or quotes in your database table that would produce weirdness in the resulting CSV at the moment).

Comment: In addition to @JeremyThompson I would advice you to use SqlParameter (https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0) instead of direct concatination of user input. This approach will protect your from sql-injection.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar You're incredible!!! I was able to make your code work in mine, and it's flawless! Thank you so much!!!